# Fast way to merge points in overlapped in same position

Tags: algorithm, duplicate-data

All:

Suppose I have tons of points (x, y), could anyone show me a fast way(simple algorithm preferred) to remove the duplicated position value points in Javascript?

What I can think about is like:
sort them by x and compare one by one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: @orlp thanks for info. My case is a little(only a little) different, it is 2d value, could you show me how to choose the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is some sort of `HashSet` for Javascript. Conveniently enough for our purposes, Javascript `Objects` behave enough like that to do what you want in a really simple way:

```
// Assuming points is an array of objects that look like {x:i, y:i}
var uniquePoints = {};
for (var i = 0; len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    uniquePoint[point.x + '_' + point.y] = point;
}
```

At the end of the `for` loop, you'll have an object containing all unique points.

Comment: Thanks for help, I think my main problem is deciding what to use as key, cos I am not sure if the value participates in string concatenation is exactly same as the value used to do calculation. For example: is that possible that the one point is [3.14159263489574936...(suppose it is very long), 5.3498375498534...], and another point is very close to it. when concatenate them as string, their results will be both "3.1415926348957493_5.3498375498534", but actually I need to keep both points?

Comment: Depending on your application's requirements for precision, I'd recommend using the `toFixed(precision)` function, which returns a string with the required precision. However, as far as I can tell, Javascript's `toString()` on a number does not lose any precision.